# Apex special character in variable

Tags: apex

I would like to know what the use of means "?" in variables.

For example, I see that I can write the code like this:

```
Account objAccount;
String variable = objAccount.Id;
```

Or write like this:

```
Account objAccount;
String variable = objAccount?.Id;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the safe navigation operator. More [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm)

> Use the safe navigation operator (?.) to replace explicit, sequential checks for null references. This operator short-circuits expressions that attempt to operate on a null value and returns null instead of throwing a NullPointerException.

Rather than the old way of writing

```
if (object.x != null){
  if (object.x.y != null){
    //do something with object.x.y
    Boolean yes = object.x.y;
  }
}
```

You can write

```
Boolean yes = object?.x?.y;
```

If either x or y are null, your `variable` variable will be null,
but it won't generate a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

It basically returns `null` if instead of `NullReferenceException`, so

```
Account acc;

System.debug(acc?.Name);
```

will display `null` instead of Exception

Answer (score 2):

`?` is not a valid character in a variable name. Variables must start with a letter, and can contain only letters, numbers, and underscores (`_`), but cannot contain more than one in a row (`my__var` is invalid as a variable name, but `my_variable_name` is acceptable). The `?` is used in two features in Apex. By itself, it is used as a ternary operator (meaning, an operator that accepts three parameters), and it can be used in `?.` as the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm).

In the ternary operator, we use it as a "shorthand" if statement:

```
Boolean someBoolean = true;
String x = someBoolean? 'Hello World': 'Goodbye World';
```

`?` must always be paired with `:` when used in this manner.

In the Safe Navigation Operator, we use it to make sure a variable is not null when we access a property:

```
Account acc;
System.debug(acc.Name); // This throws NullPointerException!
System.debug(acc?.Name); // Outputs null
```